# How to get database name automatically into script to use in stored procedure execution?

Tags: sql-server

I need to TRIM databases as per requirement. So, I'm using below script and giving database names manually. All I need is to automate the script to get database names automatically. Can anyone please suggest how to get the database name automatically.

```
Use [Sales_backup_2015_05_31_230001_7137975]
Exec [spMaint_TrimTestDB] 1
Go
```

for Eg: 
instead of giving manually `Sales_backup_2015_05_31_230001_7137975` I need to get db name automatically

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically?

Comment: Does a copy of your SP live in each db?  Is it just the connection you are interested in changing?

Comment: Please add that you want to execute an SSIS SQL Task against multiple databases. The answers in this case are *completely* different. You can use SSIS itself to change the target database, even create a loop container over the database names you want to target

Comment: You don't need to use SSIS. You can use `sp_MSForEachDB` if you want to cycle through each database. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/. However your question is very unclear. Please clarify what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `DB_NAME()` that would return the name of the current database if no parameters are passed. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx).

Comment: I need to TRIM databases using SSIS task. DB_NAME() seems does not fulfil the requirement. would that be possible to use DB_NAME() in SSIS task?  sorry I should have add in my question that I need to execute script through SSIS package

Comment: Please open you Server Manager, open a new query (where you select a specific database) and issue the command `select DB_NAME()`. This gives you the database name, which is what you asked. If this is not the answer you were looking, apparently you didn't ask the right question.

Comment: @Amelia please update your question and give *all* the relevant information. SSIS changes a *lot* of things - you can use a variable to store the database name, and change the database targeted by an `Execute SQL Task`. Trimming databases is also a *bad* idea, because you'll end up reallocating the space next time

Comment: @FDavidov the OP isn't asking to retrieve the database name, the question is how to *change* the targeted database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "_...All I need is to automate the script to get database names automatically..._. How can it be read differently?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos more: "_Can anyone please suggest how to get the database name automatically_".

Comment: No point in arguing over a very badly worded question. Both of your interpretations make sense

Answer (score 0):

I guess dynamic SQL might help you to run SP in different databases:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = (
    SELECT N'Use '+QUOTENAME([name]) +' Exec [spMaint_TrimTestDB] 1;'
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id >= 5 AND [name] like 'Sales_backup%'
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

This script will create and execute dynamic statement like:

```
Use [sales_backup_2015] Exec [spMaint_TrimTestDB] 1;
Use [sales_backup_2016] Exec [spMaint_TrimTestDB] 1;
etc...
```

Comment: Why do that when the OP could simply execute the `USE somedb` command, then execute the stored procedure without string concatenations?